# asp.net mvc large file upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, uploadify

I'm using uploadify to upload files in an asp.net mvc application. Everything works great, but when I try to upload a .. 1GB file for example - after uploadify reaches 100% it just sits there for about 2 minutes.

I added some logging code and what happens is this : when it reaches 100% the controller action is called, I get an HttpPostedFileBase and then I call file.SaveAs(path) . The "save as" takes 2 minutes. The file is moving on the same partition from the temp directory to my desired location.

Any ideas on why it takes so long ?

Thanks.

**EDIT**
Moving the file by hand is instant. Copy pasting the file takes ... 5 minutes. The SaveAs method for that file took 1m 30s.

Comment: What happens if you do the same file move directly on the server without the web application? (i.e. copy/paste manually)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactly what you want :)

But i suggest you to save the file to the same folder you want and name the file with `temp_yourFileName`
Then when you want to confirm it just rename it it'll short up the operation.

Again i believe that should be a better solution for this :)